# TypeError: $(...).style is undefined - bug or my fault?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I first wanted only to change the background of one element but then this came across:

`TypeError: $(...).style is undefined` (in the Firefox Console)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="DE">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Laura Sack - Offizielle Webseite</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="gallery-container" class="gallery-container cf"></div>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#gallery-container").style.background = "black";
});
```

Comment: it's your fault, `style` is a property of a pure JS element object not of a jQuery object, try `$("#gallery-container")[0].style` instead. However you should use the `.css` jQuery method and forget about the `style` property.

Comment: rtfm http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

Comment: `$("#gallery-container")` is a jQuery object and you are trying to style a dom node with your script, Either turn it to a dom node with including `[0]` to it like `$("#gallery-container")[0]` or as suggested use the jQuery's `.css()` method to style it.

Comment: Thanks for asking! As a back-end coder I just copied a function toggle() to show/hide DOM objects, and it turned out only `[0]` was missing. http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/ under "toggling multiple objects"

Answer (score 13):

you are mixing javascript with jquery.

In jquery you have to use [**css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to make it work like this:

```
 $("#gallery-container").css("background","black");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#gallery-container").css('background-color','black');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct jQuery method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#gallery-container").css('background-color','black');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the existence by the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   let g = $("#gallery-container");
   if(typeof g !== undefined) g.css('background','black');
});
```